# Sending Rest request with file(s) and JSON (Restsharp) on Framework and Standard

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, azure-functions, restsharp

I currently have a wrapper I am building that employs a function (SendEmail) to send a JSON payload and a few files to an Azure function at an Http endpoint. However when I am using Restsharp 106.2.2 to send over my request it seems that no boundary information is being provided. When my Azure function receives the call and tries to setup the MultipartMemoryStreamProvider it can't because it doesn't see any boundaries.

**Console Test App**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var emailService = new EmailService();
    var email = new MicroserviceMailMessage("from@test.com", "to@test.com",
        "Test Subject from Framework App", "Test Body from Framework App", true, DateTime.Now);
    email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\Temp\soccor5.jpg"));

    emailService.SendEmail(email);
}
```

**Wrapper Library**

```
public void SendEmail(MicroserviceMailMessage email)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:7071/api");
    var request = new RestRequest("SendEmail", Method.POST);

    var transformedEmail = TransformEmail(email);

    request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", $"multipart/form-data");

    foreach (var attachment in email.Attachments)
    {
        var inline = attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline ? "inline." : "";
        request.Files.Add(new FileParameter
        {
            Name = $"attachments.{inline}{attachment.Name}",
            Writer = (s) =>
            {
                attachment.ContentStream.CopyTo(s);
                attachment.ContentStream.Dispose();
            },
            ContentType = attachment.ContentType.ToString(),
            ContentLength = attachment.ContentStream.Length,
            FileName = attachment.Name
        });
    }

    request.AddParameter("email", $"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transformedEmail)}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

**Azure Reciever Function**

```
[FunctionName("EmailReceiver")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ...)
{
    ...
    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider) // Fails on this line
    ...
}
```

**Sample Data Comparison**

*Using RestSharp 106.2.2*
[image: Data with RestSharp 106.2.2]

*Using RestSharp 105.2.3 (Similar results with Postman)*
[image: Data with RestSharp 105.2.3]

**Error**

> Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a
>   'multipart' content-type header with a 'boundary'
>   parameter.\r\nParameter name: content

**What I've tried so far:**

Reverting Restsharp to 105.2.3 brings back the boundary information in the Rest request and that works great for .Net Framework, but I need the wrapper to be cross compatible between Framework and .Net Standard so this won't fully solve my problem.

Ideas? I've been trying to think if there is some way that I can manually enter the boundaries in with Restsharp 106.2.2 but I can't find a whole lot of documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't directly an answer but merely the solution I came up with to work around the problem.

I switched to Flurl.Http which the latest version is compatible with both Standard and Framework. This is how I rewrote my SendEmail function,

```
public void SendEmail(MicroserviceMailMessage email)
{
    var url = _azureEndpoint;
    var transformedEmail = TransformEmail(email);

    var content = new CapturedMultipartContent();
    content.AddJson("email", transformedEmail);

    foreach (var attachment in email.Attachments)
    {
        var inline = attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline ? "inline." : "";
        content.AddFile($"attachments.{inline}{attachment.Name}", attachment.ContentStream, attachment.Name);
    }

    url.PostAsync(content).Wait();
}
```

It posts everything I need successfully, the files, and the JSON.